Use of "not an answer" flags
Recently, I saw a few posts flagged as "not an answer" because they missed a detail in the question, and so weren't relevant answers. For example, a couple of answers to this question gave links to chengyu resources, even though the question explicitly asked about four-character idioms and not chengyu. Those answers got flagged as "not an answer".
To be clear, I am not complaining about those flags. I think the users who flagged were genuinely trying to help the community. I just want to clarify how we want to use that flag.
How does the community want to treat answers that are wrong or misguided in some way? Do you really want moderators to delete them?

In my personal opinion, the "not an answer" flag should not be used in this case. It should be used when the post doesn't try to answer the question. The most common examples are when someone posts a comment as an answer, or posts a related question as an answer.
If you think an answer is wrong, downvote it. I think it's also polite to leave a constructive comment saying why you thought it was wrong.

I absolutely agree. :) Thanks for handling them.
